# Trying to scrape google with HtmlAgilityPack - stuck at cookies site

Tags: c#, web-scraping, google-shopping

this is my first problem on this site.. so please bear with me.

I'm trying to scrape google shopping by using HtmlAgilityPack.

I have established a connection, but I'm stuck at their cookies(Which is a site that redirects you to the google shopping search afterwards - when doing it manually). So they are essentially blocking me I guess I'd say.

I've tried to follow the step by step guide looking like this:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();


HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.google.com/search?q=bicycle&source=lnms&tbm=shop");



var headernames = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants();//.Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("tAxDx"));
var titles = new List<Row>();
foreach (var headername in headernames)
{
    titles.Add(new Row
    {
        title = headername.InnerText
    });
}

foreach (var title in titles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(title.title);
}

Console.ReadLine();
public class Row
{
    public string title { get; set; }

}
```

I've outcommented my where statement - since it doesnt return anything, given we are on the cookies site.

Any ideas or thoughts on how to solve this question? I'm fairly new to scraping, and still a student developer.. So I might need some guidance. Thank you.

Note: I see alot of suggestions trying different stuff - nothing has led me further than to acces the cookies site of google. (including WebBrowser from windows)

I'm trying to scrape google shopping by using HtmlAgilityPack.

I have established a connection, but I'm stuck at their cookies(Which is a site that redirects you to the google shopping search afterwards - when doing it manually). So they are essentially blocking me I guess I'd say.

I'm trying to scrape the titles of products in the shopping view of google.